# How to change loaded svg source style dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am having problem editting svg source code that was assigned to a variable after retrieved from an ajax request.

```
//my html
<div class="col col-md-12">
    <div class="my-svg" id="show-logo" >
</div>



//javascript
var obj = {category: 'SPORT'}   
$.ajax({
        url : '{{ route("getsvgs") }}',
        type: 'GET',
        data: obj,
        success : function(response, statut){
            var svg_img = response.logo;
            //the ajax request is going on successful and returning the 
            //above svg code.
          $('#show-logo').append(svg_img );
          localStorage._el = JSON.stringify(response);//store localstorage
        },

    error : function(response, statut, error){
        console.log(response);
    },

    complete : function(responce, statut){
        console.log('completed');
    }
});
```

from what you can see the svg is been appended to the div and showing. here is the svg code

```
/* response.logo = <svg class="image-svg" id="svg-logo" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 298.63 86.14">
    <title>left</title>
    <text class="svg-logo-name" transform="translate(63.81 65.42)"></text>
    <text class="svg-logo-slogan" transform="translate(66.36 81.64)">logo slogan goes here</text>
    <path class="frontcolor" d="M70.74,172.32c5.11,4,13.08,4.11,16.84,3.32a0.82,0.82,0,0,1-.15,0c-6.82-1.45-11.1-3.74-14.81-7.09s-6.09-7.69-7.55-14.05C65.06,154.5,62.42,165.76,70.74,172.32Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <path class="backcolor" d="M93.94,181.92c-14.44,4.56-25.63-7-25.63-7a0.24,0.24,0,0,1,.15,0c5.64,3.63,15.69,4.76,23.33,1.87,9.63-3.64,16.27-12.5,16.58-20.72C108.38,156.12,110,176.85,93.94,181.92Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <path class="frontcolor" d="M113.53,202.4c-6.95-6.67-17.78-6.8-22.9-5.49a0.71,0.71,0,0,1,.21,0c9.27,2.4,15.1,6.2,20.14,11.75s8.28,12.76,10.27,23.3C121.25,231.94,124.85,213.27,113.53,202.4Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <path class="backcolor" d="M82,186.47c19.63-7.56,34.84,11.53,34.84,11.53a0.28,0.28,0,0,1-.21,0c-7.67-6-21.34-7.9-31.72-3.1-13.09,6-22.12,20.72-22.54,34.35C62.36,229.24,60.17,194.89,82,186.47Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <ellipse class="frontcolor" cx="25.18" cy="9.3" rx="9.25" ry="9.3"/>
</svg> */
```

Now when trying to edit the svg like this nothing is happening.

```
$(".svg-logo-name text").css("font-size", "48px");
$(".frontcolor text").css("fill", "#eeeeee");
$(".backcolor text").css("fill", "#ccddee");
```

Nothing is been applied. how can I achieved that? please.

Comment: Your selectors are wrong. `.svg-logo-name` _is_ the `text` element.

Comment: The selectors are wrong. All three of your selectors are looking for an element with a descendant element of `text`. None of your SVG elements have descendants besides the `<svg>` element itself.

Comment: how can I edit it to work then? because I changed to this but still the same pb.$(".svg-logo-name").css("font-size", "48px");
  $(".frontcolor").css("fill", "#eeeeee");
  $(".backcolor").css("fill", "#ccddee");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors are wrong. All three of your selectors are looking for an element with a descendant element of `text`. None of your SVG elements have descendants besides the `<svg>` element itself.

Remove `text` from your CSS selectors. Also, **very important**, you cannot run the jQuery that modifies the styles until the SVG markup has been added to the DOM (your DIV), otherwise it won't find those elements to modify. Run the jQuery in the *success* or *complete* callbacks.

```js
$( '.svg-logo-name' ).css( 'font-size', '48px' );
$( '.frontcolor' ).css( 'fill', '#eee' );
$( '.backcolor' ).css( 'fill', '#cde' );

// Above code would go here:
// $.ajax( {
//   success: function ( response, status ) {
//
//     $( '#show-logo' ).append( response.logo );
//     
//     // Modify SVG.
//     $( '.svg-logo-name' ).css( 'font-size', '48px' );
//     $( '.frontcolor' ).css( 'fill', '#eee' );
//     $( '.backcolor' ).css( 'fill', '#cde' );
//
//  }
// } );
//
// Or it would go here:
// $.ajax( {
//   complete: function ( xhr, status ) {
//     
//     // Modify SVG.
//     if ( 'success' === status ) {
//
//       $( '.svg-logo-name' ).css( 'font-size', '48px' );
//       $( '.frontcolor' ).css( 'fill', '#eee' );
//       $( '.backcolor' ).css( 'fill', '#cde' );
//
//     }
//
//  }
// } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="image-svg" id="svg-logo" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 298.63 86.14">
    <title>left</title>
    <text class="svg-logo-name" transform="translate(63.81 65.42)"></text>
    <text class="svg-logo-slogan" transform="translate(66.36 81.64)">logo slogan goes here</text>
    <path class="frontcolor" d="M70.74,172.32c5.11,4,13.08,4.11,16.84,3.32a0.82,0.82,0,0,1-.15,0c-6.82-1.45-11.1-3.74-14.81-7.09s-6.09-7.69-7.55-14.05C65.06,154.5,62.42,165.76,70.74,172.32Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <path class="backcolor" d="M93.94,181.92c-14.44,4.56-25.63-7-25.63-7a0.24,0.24,0,0,1,.15,0c5.64,3.63,15.69,4.76,23.33,1.87,9.63-3.64,16.27-12.5,16.58-20.72C108.38,156.12,110,176.85,93.94,181.92Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <path class="frontcolor" d="M113.53,202.4c-6.95-6.67-17.78-6.8-22.9-5.49a0.71,0.71,0,0,1,.21,0c9.27,2.4,15.1,6.2,20.14,11.75s8.28,12.76,10.27,23.3C121.25,231.94,124.85,213.27,113.53,202.4Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <path class="backcolor" d="M82,186.47c19.63-7.56,34.84,11.53,34.84,11.53a0.28,0.28,0,0,1-.21,0c-7.67-6-21.34-7.9-31.72-3.1-13.09,6-22.12,20.72-22.54,34.35C62.36,229.24,60.17,194.89,82,186.47Z" transform="translate(-62.3 -148.4)"/>
    <ellipse class="frontcolor" cx="25.18" cy="9.3" rx="9.25" ry="9.3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: still not working, can the fact that i am loaded the svg from the variable can be the problem?

Comment: Possibly, when are you running the jQuery that modifies the styles? The SVG needs to be inserted into the page before you can access the DOM elements of the SVG with jQuery. Run the jQuery in the _success_ or _complete_ callbacks. If you use _complete_ you'll want to check if the request completed successfully first.

Comment: I running that directly after the ajax request.

Comment: So like this, `$.ajax(...code...); $( '.svg-logo-name' ).css()`? If so, that won't work. You need to put the jQuery that modifies the elements in the _success_ or _complete_ callback of the ajax method.

Comment: hmmm, how can I do that ?

Comment: Put your jQuery that modifies the SVG elements in the _success_ or _complete_ callback. If you use _complete_ you'll want to check if the request was successful.

Comment: ooooh!, it works thanks for the help, I appreciate it. :)